# rs.Open SQL not opening file?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ado

Don't you hate it when a program worked last month and now it fails.

I have an Access procedure that executes this (counts rows in the table with the matching date):

```
StrSearchCriteria = "SELECT Ticker " _
    & "FROM FundMonthlyDetailAllHistory " _
    & "WHERE AsOfDate = #" & DDate & "#; "
rs.Open StrSearchCriteria, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
i = 1
Do Until rs.EOF
    i = i + 1
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
```

This works great; no problem.

About 300 lines down the procedure I have this:

```
StrSearchCriteria = "SELECT Ticker, FundStatus, Category, AsOfDate " _
    & "FROM FundMonthlyDetailCurrent " _
    & "ORDER BY Category, FundStatus"
rs.Open StrSearchCriteria, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
StrCategory = " "
i = 1
Do Until rs.EOF
    If StrCategory = rs!Category Then
        i = i + 1
    Else
        i = 1
    End If
    rs!CurrentRank = i
    StrCategory = rs!Category
    DDate = rs!AsOfDate     ' save the As of Date for later processing
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
```

This sorts and counts rows by "Category".

The loop never ends because it appears the open fails, although Access seems to think everything is fine for the open. If I try to check the value of rs.Category in the Immediate window with ?rs.Category I receive a "run timer error 3704" "Operation not allowed when the object is closed"

I have verified that the table has the data as expected and that the code was not changed since last month's run of the procedure.

I decided to try last month's data again - and this also failed at the same code.

Any thoughts are appreciated? Windows/Access update maybe? I'm at a loss.

Comment: Add tag for programming language - is this VBA?

Comment: @June7: It is ADO in VBA.

Comment: I ran your code, and it runs as expected without any errors. So, you are probably not posting the full story.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to tell the "full story". Is it possible an update to Windows or Access is causing the problem?

Comment: Solved... For whatever reason that I am not aware, some of the fields in the database changed Result Type from Double to Decimal. You cannot sort on Decimal fields, so the SELECT statement was failing.